# Show embed youtube video from database to web using php

Tags: php

i want to display embed video from database and display it to web browser but the syntax eror "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\iklan2\vid2.php on line 3"

[this is the eror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPnSf.png)

Comment: You forgot a semicolon on line 2. `include_once "config.php";`

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a semicolon after include (include_once "config.php"; )